Can I sand these bamboo floors that have uneven wear and just reseal them without staining to keep lighter color?
Just bought this house with bamboo floors (red wood), that’s worn and now looking like a hiking trail around the house, can I sand them into the worn color (lighter color) and just seal them, as I like that color better. Or does bamboo require some special care? And if I can just sand and seal what kind of sealant would I use?


A lot depends upon the type of material the floor is built from. Planks like shown in the picture may very well be an engineered flooring material that is made up of a plywood type construction with just the very top layer being the bamboo. Some products have this top material very thin - so thin that any type of robust sanding would wear right through to the inner layers. Those inner layers are likely not the same material and if they are the same material the grain direction changes with each layer.
Also keep in mind that bamboo is a very stringy and fibrous material and would require gentle sanding if it is undertaken. I would personally not recommend sanding any bamboo with the typical 36 or 40 grit sanding pads used on commercial floor sanders.
Another thing to consider is that plank type flooring has two additional factors:

It typically comes original from the factory pre-finished. This finish may be very difficult to sand off when using a gentle sanding approach.
Plank type flooring often has micro bevel edges between the plank sides and ends. (Your flooring appears to have these as seen in the photos). Sanding can change the appearance of these a lot, especially if the sanding is not fully uniform across the floor.

